# $G_n:=\sqrt{n} \left(X_n-1\right) \xrightarrow[n]{d} N(\mu,\sigma^2) $ implies $\sqrt{n} \left(1-X_n^{-1}\right)=G_n+o_P(1)$

Tags: probability, statistics, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion, normal-distribution

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of RV so that $G_n:=\sqrt{n} \left(X_n-1\right) \underset{n \to \infty}{\overset{d}{\longrightarrow}} G \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.

I want to show that in this case
$\sqrt{n} \left(1-X_n^{-1}\right)=G_n+o_P(1).$

I had planned to use the function $h(x)=1-1/x, \quad x\ne 0,\quad$ on $X_n \textbf{1}_{\{X_n
\ne 0\}}$ and do a Taylor expansion in $1$ but don't know how to handle the case $X_n =0$, even if I split $h$ up into $h|_{x<0}$ and $h|_{x>0}$. From the above follows that $X_n {\overset{P}{\longrightarrow}} 1 $, so $P(X_n =0) \overset{n}{\longrightarrow} 0$ but I'm not sure how to make use of that.

<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

Here is what I was planning to do so you've got a better idea:

In the case $X_n>0$ I get
$1-X_n^{-1}=h(X_n)=h(1)+h'(\xi_n)(X_n-1)=h'(\xi_n)(X_n-1)$ for some $\xi_n$ between $1$ and $X_n$.

From $X_n {\overset{P}{\longrightarrow}} 1$ follows $\xi_n {\overset{P}{\longrightarrow}} 1$ in case $X_n>0$ (is this even true?) and with the Continuous Mapping Theorem I get $h'(\xi_n) {\overset{P}{\longrightarrow}} h'(1)=1,$ so $h(\xi_n)=1+o_P(1).$

Now I have something like

$\sqrt{n} \left( 1-X_n^{-1}\right)=\sqrt{n}\, h(X_n)\textbf{1}_{\{X_n
> 0\}}+\sqrt{n} \left( 1-X_n^{-1}\right)\textbf{1}_{\{X_n
\le 0\}}$
$=h'(\xi_n)\, G_n\textbf{1}_{\{X_n
> 0\}}+\sqrt{n} \left( 1-X_n^{-1}\right)\textbf{1}_{\{X_n
\le 0\}}$
$=(1+o_P(1))\, G_n\textbf{1}_{\{X_n
> 0\}}+\sqrt{n} \left( 1-X_n^{-1}\right)\textbf{1}_{\{X_n
\le 0\}}$

Now I don't know what to do with the rest and I'm not even sure if the Taylor expansion is the right path to take here.

Answer (score 1):

This is a proof for $\mu = 0$. When $\mu \neq 0$, the proof can be done with some slight modification.

You want to prove $\sqrt{n}(1-X_n^{-1}) - G_n = \sqrt{n}(2-X_n^{-1}-X_n)$ converges to $0$ in probability, which is equivalently that it converges to $0$ in distribution.

To do this, we can apply the second order delta method(for reference see [this](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cme308/OldWebsite/notes/TaylorAppDeltaMethod.pdf)) with the function $g(x) = x + \frac{1}{x}$.

Since $g'(x) = 1 -\dfrac{1}{x^2}$ and $g''(x) = \dfrac{2}{x^3}$, we have $g'(1) = 0$ and $g''(1) = 2$, the second order delta method says:

$$n(g(X_n) - g(1)) \to \sigma^2\chi_1^2 \text{ in distribution}$$

then we have

$$\sqrt{n}(g(X_n) - g(1)) \to 0 \text{ in distribution}$$ 
which is the desired result.

Comment: Did you mean the function $g(x)=-x-\frac{1}{x}$? I don't understand the last step you made. Also, how do I define $g(X_n)$ for $X_n=0$? As $\infty?$

Comment: @user3018 yeah you can add the negative sign, it doesn't change the steps. For the last step, you can suppose the convergence to $0$ is not true then get a contradiction with the statement before last. How to define $g(X_n)$ when $X_n=0$ does not matter, you can define it in the same way as you define $X_n^{-1}$

Comment: Ah, now I understand the last step. Thanks. Is there a better (more official) source for the second order delta method? And does it matter that $G \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ for $\mu \ne 0?$ I guess it would be $G^2$ in the limit distribution instead of $\chi ^2_1$, right?

Comment: @user3018 I don't know other sources. I know this method when once answering a question on this site. Sorry I didn't notice that $\mu\neq 0$, then some modification is needed. See in the reference how the second order delta method is roughly proved, you can easily modify my answer(probably by replacing the $\chi_1^2$ by something else.) But the idea of this solution still works